# Using Eukleides

Tags: diagrams

Some background; I am a math teacher and am currently teaching Geometry. Now, I want to make documents containg pretty triangles, squares and lines. My question is twofold:

1. What is the best package to do this?
2. I stumbled upon the package Eukleides, but I cannot get it to work. Does anyone have any insight into what I might have done wrong? I have MikTeX and followed the instructions in the readme for the Eukleides package for Windows. But when I try to make a simple triangle, I can't produce anything.

I was asked for more details on the installation of Eukleides. I downloaded the binary from eukleides.org. I unzipped it and placed 'eukleides', 'euktopst', 'euktotex', and 'euktopdf' in 'C:\Program Files\MikTeX 2.9\miktex\bin'.
Then I placed the LaTeX packages ('eukleides.tex' and 'eukleides.sty') in 'C:\Program Files\MikTeX 2.9\tex\latex'.

I tried making a file called 'triangle.euk' which only contained the following lines:

```
A B C triangle
draw(A,B,C)
```

Now I tried opening 'triangle.euk' with all four of the programs with no result. I tried opening the three examples (these are included in the binary) and I got partial results. When I opened the examples in 'eukleides', it produced .eps files. These opens nicely. But my triangle does not even compile it seems.

Since I "installed" the LaTeX-package too, I gave it a shot there as well:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,norsk]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eukleides}

\begin{document}
\begin{eukleides}
A B C triangle
I = incircle(A,B,C)
draw(A,B,C) ; draw(I)
\end{eukleides}
\end{document}
```

This does not produce an error, it just produces a blank page... I am puzzled.

Comment: `tkz-euclide` would be my first choice. It's based on TikZ and makes things really really  easy. (Written by our [Alain Matthes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3144/alain-matthes) )

Comment: Since Eukleides has a pstricks output, perhaps you could give a direct try at `pstricks` and more specifically at `pst-eucl`, one of the members of the pstricks family that is is dedicated to plane euclidean geometry. One advantage of pstricks is that its syntax is LaTeX-like, and nowadays, with the auto-pst-pdf, it can be compiled with `pdfLaTeX`.

Comment: The point of Eukleidis was that the code was highly readable, while both tkz and pst is quite greek to an average student. Also, the code in Eukleidis looks quite similar to the requirements when you document a construction with a ruler and a compass.

Comment: Please post your complete efforts --- how did you install Eukleides, and a minimal example file and the command which you used to attempt to process it.

Comment: Are you certain that the .eps files aren't already present for the examples? What happens when you run `eukleides triangle.euk`?

Comment: As stated in the text, running eukleides triangle.euk results in absolutely nothing. Nothing crashes or anything, it is just that nothing happens. I thought briefly that it maybe had a default location that it placed the output .eps-file, but when I run the examples, the produced .eps appears in the same folder as the example-files. The .eps-files are not present as I can see them appear when running the program with the examples. Do you have personal experience with the program WillAdams?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will have the easiest starting if you use TikZ for this. The manual already shows some examples for such things. You will have no problems in finding the packages on CTAN or with choosing the TeX-compiler.

As mentioned by percusse, there is already a TikZ front-end for Euclidean geometry which is called [`tkz-euclide`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide).

Here are three examples I just copied from the manual:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,
    2/0/B,
    2/2/C,
    0/2/D}
\tkzDrawSegments(D,A A,B B,C C,D)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,D)
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,rotate=-30]
\tkzDefPoint(2,3){A}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[A](0:4){B}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[A](30:4){C}
\tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C C,A)
\tkzMarkSegments[mark=|,color=red](A,B A,C)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
\tkzLabelPoints(B,C) \tkzLabelPoints[above left](A)
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.4]
\tkzDefPoint(2,3){A} \tkzDefPoint(5,-1){B}
\tkzDefPoint[label=below:$\mathcal{C}$,
shift={(2,3)}](-30:5.5){E}
\begin{scope}[shift=(A)]
\tkzDefPoint(30:5){C}
\end{scope}
\tkzCalcLength[cm](A,B)\tkzGetLength{rAB}
\tkzDrawCircle[R](A,\rAB cm)
\tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
\tkzLabelPoints(B,C)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](A)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the proposal. I guess I am stuck with tikz, although I really had hoped that eukleides would work.